# Find an LL(2) grammar for the following language

Tags: logic, automata, regular-language, context-free-grammar

The question asks to find both an LL(1) and an LL(2) grammar for the following language

`{^ ^ ^+ | m,n ϵ N}`

I have an LL(1) grammar like so

```
S --> aSc | T
T --> bTc | \lambda
```

But what is the LL(2) grammar? I have this, but I don't feel confident in it

```
LL(2)
S --> aaScc | aSc | T
T --> bbTcc | bTc | $\Lambda$
```

Comment: yes I'd say it is $LL(2)$ since (during parsing) it has to check $2$ tokens ahead to see if one should apply the rule $S \to aaScc$ or the rule $S \to aSc$, and it doesn't need backtracking. and honestly I don't see what could be the answer if it is not that grammar

Comment: maybe you could do something : the rule $S \to a S c$ you can replace it by $S \to a T c$, and the rule $T \to b T c$ replaced by $T \to bc$

Answer (score 1):

The question doesn't make sense: the $n$ in $LL(n)$ is a property of a language not a grammar.

An $LL(n)$ language is one that can be parsed by an [$LL$ parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser) that uses at most $n$ look-ahead tokens. So any $LL(1)$ language is $LL(2)$ (because a parser can just ignore the second look-ahead token).